# Python3 Program wont write to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv

myfile = open ('score sheet.csv','a+')
score = 0
data = score
myfile.write (str(data))
myfile.close
```

This is a small section of code from a larger program. And in that program I have another csv file that works fine so not sure why this doesnt work

Comment: Well here you do not write a csv stream, and you also do not *close* the file handler, you should *call* the `close()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

"close" is a function, you need to call it with `myfile.close()` <- note the paranthesis